# mySQL all results with score less than a value in every case

Tags: mysql, sql

Scores with studentID, studentScore, subject

assume table scores has this

```
1 40 maths
3 20 english
2 23 english
1 30 english
4 10 maths
```

a table called students, with studentID,studentName

assume table students has this

```
1 John Smith
2 anne grey
3 bob lemons
4 chris something
```

I want students names,score,subject where all of their scores are below 31, so John smith has 1 over 31 (40) so he doesnt count in the result

should be this result

```
bob lemons 20 english
anne grey 23 english
chris something 10 maths
```

Cheers.

Comment: Is this not as simple as `SELECT studentName, studentScore, subject FROM students INNER JOIN scores ON scores.studentID = students.studentID WHERE studentScore < 31` or something similar?

Comment: You want to do this, what have you done so far and where are u stuck?

Comment: ive tried that way before, that will still return john smith because one of his scores is lower than 31 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT s.studentName, sc.score, sc.subject
FROM students s JOIN scores sc ON sc.studentID = s.studentID
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
                   FROM scores ss
                   WHERE ss.studentID = s.studentID
                   AND ss.studentScore > 30
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
 select st.studentName
      , sc.score
      , sc.subject
 from students st
 join scores sc on sc.studentID = st.studentID
 join (
      select studentID
      from scores
      group by studentID
      having max(studentScore) < 31
 ) t2 on t2.studentID = st.studentID
```

The concept is as follows: if student has a score higher than 31 within a group of scores, the group us excluded from the result set.

Comment: You must change `min(studentScore)` to `max(studentScore)` and there's no need for an Outer join, better change it to Inner and remove the `WHERE`

Comment: You don't need an anti-join as you're not searching for `t2.studentID is null`. And Inner joins always perform better :-)